# Symfony router link in form label

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm looking for possibility to embed router link in Symfony 5 form label.
I need to add link to *Terms of use* page in registartion form type.

Here is part of my code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // some code
        ->add('terms', CheckboxType::class, [
            'label' => 'I accept <a href="/terms" target="_blank">Terms of use</a>', // <= here I need router link instead of '/terms' 
            'label_attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-check-label'
            ],
            'label_html' => true,
            'mapped' => false
        ])
        //some other code
    ;
}
```

I know, that I can use **TWIG**, but I'm looking for PHP possibility ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject the router in your FormType and generate the link with it.

```
class FormType extends AbstractType{

    private $router;

    function __construct(RouterInterface $router){
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $tosUrl = $this->router->generate('terms');
        
        $builder
            // some code
            ->add('terms', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'I accept <a href="' . $tosUrl .'" target="_blank">Terms of use</a>',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-check-label'
                ],
                'label_html' => true,
                'mapped' => false
            ])
            //some other code
        ;
    }
}
```